# bind first argument of function without knowing its arity

Tags: c++, c++11, functional-programming, c++14, bind

I'd like to have a function `BindFirst` that binds the first argument of a function without me having to explicitly know/state the arity of the function by using std::placeholders. I'd like the client code to look something like that.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void print2(int a, int b)
{
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
}

void print3(int a, int b, int c)
{
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}

int main()
{ 
    auto f = BindFirst(print2, 1); // std::bind(print2, 1, std::placeholders::_1);
    auto g = BindFirst(print3, 1); // std::bind(print3, 1, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
    f(2);
    g(2,3);
}
```

Any ideas how `BindFirst` could be implemented?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename F, typename T>
struct binder
{
    F f; T t;
    template <typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... args) const
        -> decltype(f(t, std::forward<Args>(args)...))
    {
        return f(t, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

template <typename F, typename T>
binder<typename std::decay<F>::type
     , typename std::decay<T>::type> BindFirst(F&& f, T&& t)
{
    return { std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<T>(t) };
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7122bda401090e8)

In [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14):

```
#include <utility>

template <typename F, typename T>
auto BindFirst(F&& f, T&& t)
{
    return [f = std::forward<F>(f), t = std::forward<T>(t)]
           (auto&&... args)
           { return f(t, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); };
}
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23ae8d1aba897799)

Comment: can I know why `std::decay` is used?

Comment: @billz Because here we want to store copies (possibly move-constructed) of the arguments passed to `BindFirst`. You certainly don't want to store references, neither their constness/volatileness is of your interest here. Say, for `T&&=int&&` you want to store `int`

Answer (score 0):

Let a [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) implementation be here too:

```cpp
template <typename Base, typename... Head>
[[nodiscard]] auto bind_head(Base&& func, Head&&... args) {
    return [base{std::forward<Base>(func)}, head{std::make_tuple(std::forward<Head>(args)...)}](auto&&... tail) mutable {
        return std::apply(base, std::tuple_cat(head, std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<decltype(tail)>(tail)...)));
    };
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3218336989e1d1ec)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I was wondering if You can do that in C++, then I realized that simple variadic macro in C should be enough.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define bindFirst(functionName, firstArgument, ...) \
        functionName(firstArgument, __VA_ARGS__)

void print2(int a, int b) {
  printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
}

void print3(int a, int b, int c) {
  printf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, c);
}

int main() {
  
    // To get same effect as OP wanted:
    // 
    // auto f = BindFirst(print2, 1); // std::bind(print2, 1, std::placeholders::_1);
    // auto g = BindFirst(print3, 1); // std::bind(print3, 1, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
    // f(2);
    // g(2,3);


    #define f(...) bindFirst(print2, 1, __VA_ARGS__)
    #define g(...) bindFirst(print3, 1, __VA_ARGS__)

    f(2);
    g(2,3);

    #undef f
    #undef g
  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't do something equivalent to `std::bind` in general

Comment: @Caleth Of course it is not replacement for all the cases of std::bind, it is for a very specific use case which OP posted.

Comment: "I'd like to have a function `BindFirst`" a macro is not a function